# Как подключить в ASP.NET Core Lazy loading?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Всем привет. при работе с ASP.NET Core столкнулся с такой проблемой. 
Есть две модели

```
public class Room: BaseEntity
{
    [Display(Name = "Наименование")]
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Комментарий")]
    [JsonPropertyName("comment")]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RoomType")]
    [Display(Name = "Тип помещения")]
    public int IdRoomType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Тип помещения")]
    public virtual RoomType RoomType { get; set; }
}
public class RoomType: BaseEntity
{
    [Display(Name = "Наименование")]
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Использую EF. И при получении экземпляра `Room` поле `IdRoomType` заполнено, а само `RoomType` равно `Null`. То есть lazy loading не работает. В интернете нашёл, что в ASP.NET lazy loading подключается так: в методе `ConfigureServices` файлы `Startup.cs` нужно написать следующее:

```
services.AddDbContext<DataModel>(options =>
                options
                    .UseUseLazyLoadingProxies()
                    .UseSqlServer(
                        Configuration.GetConnectionString("ALRConnection"), option => option.UseRelationalNulls())
                            );
```

Но студия не видит метод  `UseUseLazyLoadingProxies`. Как можно решить эту проблему? и на сколько правильно использовать lazy loading?

Comment: `UseUse` - уверены?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, это просто опечатка. метода UseLazyLoadingProxies студия не видит

Answer (score 0):

`UseLazyLoadingProxies` - этот метод является частью отдельного пакета: [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies), установите его и он появится.